# Opening PWA from FB app in external browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, progressive-web-apps, firebase-dynamic-links

We have a PWA linked to the Facebook advertisement. The problem is when clicking the advertisement from the FB app, it opens the PWA with FB's internal browser which doesn't support PWA features.

*Question:* Is there a way to open the PWA from FB post or any workaround for the problem? I have tried with dynamic links, but the link is also open in FB app internal browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way you can control how Facebook app behave. Instead, they allow user to choose whether to open link externally. User can go Settings -> Media & Contacts -> Links open externally to disabled the option.

Reference: https://countdownwebdesign.com/quick-tip-open-facebook-links-in-chrome/